# Implementing a hierarchical tree editor with mxGraph

Tags: javascript, mxgraph, jgraph

I would like to implement an editor for dialogue trees with mxGraph.

I started out with the *workfloweditor* example [1] and try to customize the code to my needs. Drawing the graph using the *subprocess* template as nodes and directed connectors works perfectly. However, the graph **hierarchy** seems to be missing: The tooltip always shows "Children: 0", no matter how many nodes I connect. Same happens in the original sample code.

How can I explicitly configure the graph to follow a hierarchical parent-children layout?

[1] https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/editors/workfloweditor.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The children are not what I think you think.

What is a children? These are cells with current cell as a parent. What is a parent ? Try that : Add a box, right click on it and click "enter group". You are now inside in sub-process if you like. Place a few boxes there, then right click on the canvas "exit group". Now you have a parent cell with children cells.

What you are trying to do is to read the connections between your boxes. Have a look at [how to traverse the graph](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/view/mxGraph-js.html#mxGraph.traverse) or you can implement manually too, it's fairly straightforward.